# How to remove Report Server only?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I've gone ahead and configured the Report Server after SQL Server installation, and as part of that I've ended up with: 
1) a report server database and
2) a link (I think in 2016 they call it Web Portal), where reports are to be deployed I guess.

I realized this was incorrect, I should not have configured/installed Report Server to begin with. I need to remove ***REPORT SERVER*** **without** removing Reporting Services. **To be specific,** I need the link (the Web Portal, or the link Report Server puts up) REMOVED and the Report Server database removed also.

The ***ONLY*** instructions I get are for removing Reporting Services, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143518(v=sql.90).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479745.aspx) , all that's talked about is removing Reporting Services. I just need the Report SERVER (DBs) and Report Server LINK to be removed. How do I accomplish that?

I'm using SQL Server 2016. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to keep Reporting Services without the databases and RS portal?

Comment: Report server is launched on a sharePoint on another server, so I dont need Report Server/DB ,

Comment: You should be able to go into Reporting Services Configuration Manager and remove the URLs for the RS portals (Manager and Reports) and stop the Reporting Services. Then in SSMS, drop the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases.

Comment: Reporting Services is a three-part feature made up of the Web Service, the Web Portal, (Report Manager), and the Database. Just to be clear, you want to remove the portal and the database, but not the service, right?

Answer (score 1):

To take the Reporting Services databases out of commission on this server without disrupting the service itself, you'll need to point the service to databases elsewhere. To do this, open Reporting Services Configuration Manager on the server running the RS service, and change the "Database Name" entry in the Database menu page:

[image: Reporting Services Configuration Manager Database page]

To shut down the Report Manager web portal, open up the RSReportServer.config file. This is located in the install directory (usually *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\[Instance Name]\Reporting Services\ReportServer*).

Under the `<Service>` element, there will be several elements that begin with "Is". These control which services/functions are enabled. The last entry will be `<IsReportManagerEnabled>`.

[image]

Change this value from True to False. Save the file and close.

Some changes to RSReportServer.config require a service restart, so you may have to restart the RS service to get this change to stick. Once it does, the RS service will no longer respond to requests to the Report Manager portal but the separate web service that processes report requests will continue running.

You can read more about RSReportServer.config and switching individual services on/off here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx#bkmk_service